# How to force log4j to be used but not slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

**EDIT:** To clarify the question, I added many explanations.

In my project dependencies, I have both `slf4j` and `log4j`. This can't be changed for some technical reason.

```
>gradlew dependencies
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could 
not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :dependencies
.
.
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.5.7
|    |         |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.7
|    |         |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.7
|    |         |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32
|    |         |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.14.1
|    |         |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.32
|    |         |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1 -> 2.17.0
|    |         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.32
|    |         |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32
.
.
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 16s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I want to [set the log level in the code](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html#setLevel-java.util.Map-), and AFAIK that can only be done with `log4j`. As a result, I simply look for a way to make this code line (`LogManager` is part of `log4j`) returns `log4j` implementation and not `slf4j` implementation:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
.
.
private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
```

Sadly, the logger's class returns is `org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger`:

```
System.out.println("logger class is: [" + logger.getClass() + "]");
```

output:

```
logger class is: [class org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger]
```

Even though it sounds easy, I haven't been able to do it or find an example online. What can be done?

Comment: *It will return log4j implementation and not slf4j implementation. Sadly, it returns slf4j.* **What** do you mean?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch sorry, I fixed it

Comment: I would not say you have *fixed it*. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give us something to work with. A single line of code and an incomprehensible assertion are not enough.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can add as many lines as you like, but this is unfortunately the only line that relates to the problem.

Comment: @yoni: what is the fully qualified class name of `logger`? My guess is you expect `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger`, but obtain `org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger`. Is this what happens? Can you add the fqcn of the factory `LogManager.getFactory()`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I appreciate your help. To answer your first question (_what is the fully qualified class name of logger?_), please see my edit in the question. Regarding your second question (_Is this what happens?_), the answer is yes. In answer to your third question (_fqcn of the factory_), I am not sure how to get this information. Could you please give me a syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Log4j 2.x Core](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html) and the [Log4j to SLF4J Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) are two implementations of the Log4j 2.x API. If they are both present on the classpath `log4j-to-slf4j` is used. That is what happens in your case: messages logged using the Log4j 2.x API are sent to SLF4J, which sends them to Logback.

That is the standard logging configuration brought by the [`spring-boot-starter-logging`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging). If you want to use Log4j 2 as backend instead you need to exclude that artifact and add [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2).

Anyway, since you are using Spring Boot, you have two ways to set the level of a logger:

1. Using Spring Boot's [`LoggingSystem`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem.html) abstraction (works for all available logging systems):

   ```java
   final LoggingSystem loggingSystem = LoggingSystem.get(getClass().getClassLoader());
   loggingSystem.setLogLevel("loggerName", LogLevel.DEBUG);
   ```
2. Using the underlying logging system. In your case it is Logback, so you should use:

   ```java
   final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("loggerName");
   if (logger instanceof ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) {
       ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) logger).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
   }
   ```

**Remark:** due to recent vulnerabilities in both Log4j and Logback, you should bump your version of Spring Boot to 2.5.8 (or 2.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

Whats the full class path of LogManager? It has to be imported, there you should see the full class.

My guess is that you need to change the Import to import some log4j LogManager, not the slf4j one.

Comment: The `LogManager` is class of `log4j`: The import is: `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;`